# Use cmd.run in setting a grains

Tags: bash, salt-stack

For a project I want to set a timestamp in a saltstack grains using modules.
But I didn't figure how to do it with cmd.run...
For the moment, I try something like that :

```
salt-call grains.set date_install_minion salt['cmd.run']('date -u')
salt-call grains.set date_install_minion {% salt['cmd.run']('date -u') %}
salt-call grains.set date_install_minion {{ salt['cmd.run']('date -u') }}
...
```

Somebody know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the output of `cmd.run` into a `grains.set` command might not work in the same step as there is no Jinja context available. That said, a good way to add [custom grains](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/grains/index.html) in Saltstack is by putting them in `/etc/salt/grains` file.

This file can be updated with key value pairs in YAML format. One way to update it with command:

```
echo "date_install_minion: $(date -u)" >> /etc/salt/grains
```

Otherwise set the `date` to Shell variable, and use the shell variable in `grains.set`:

```
MINION_INSTALL_DATE=$(date -u)
salt-call grains.set date_install_minion "$MINION_INSTALL_DATE"
```

Comment: Thanks it's work very well !
If somebody needs this answer, just don't forget to restart salt-minion after ;)

Comment: There is also a `saltutil.refresh_grains` to refresh the grains data.

Comment: No need for a variable: `salt-call grains.set date_install_minion "$(date -u)"`